# Nuxt 3 extends the project with the plugin which has different implementation cause "Cannot redefine property" error

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have two nuxt3 projects (Project A and B). The project B will extends the project A.

The nuxt config and the axios plugin from project A.

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  ssr: false
})
```

```
import axios from "axios"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  return {
    provide: {
        axios: axios
    }
  }
})
```

The nuxt config and my custom axios plugin from project B.

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  extends: [
    '../project-a'
  ]
})
```

```
import axios from "axios"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  // Some extra implementation for setting the http interceptor
  return {
    provide: {
        axios: axios
    }
  }
})
```

There is an error when starting the project B

```
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $axios
```

It seems like when overriding the plugin, the same plugin with different implementation cannot be redefined, because it exists from the project A.

Is it possible to override the plugin when extending the project in nuxt3?

Comment: In nuxt3, you can use `$fetch` instead of axios. @user3717119